# Seeking recommendations for repairing scratches on old photos

Tags: artificial-intelligence

I have a collection of old photos that have suffered from scratches over time. I'm looking for software recommendations that specialize in repairing such scratches and restoring the photos to their original quality.

Specifically, I would like the software to have the following features:

1. Ability to identify and remove scratches from scanned images.
2. Options for adjusting contrast, brightness, and color balance to enhance the overall appearance.
3. Intuitive user interface for ease of use, as I don't have advanced editing skills.
4. Compatibility with both Windows and macOS operating systems.

I would greatly appreciate any recommendations from the community based on personal experience or knowledge. Thank you in advance for your assistance!